# Excluding enclosed delimiters with cut

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, cut

Let's say I have a CSV file:

```
"col1","col2","col3"
"col4","col5,subtext","col6
```

The problem I have is as follows :

```
cut -d, -f1,2 test.txt
"coll1","col2"
"col4","col5
```

The desired output is :

```
"col1","col2"
"col4","col5,subtext"
```

Comment: @iruvar, thanks, neat solution, but unfortunately the script also needs to work on OS X (i.e. BSD) and so I can't assume gawk is available, unfortunatley.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ParseWords module, which ships with Perl, covers this quite elegantly.  Example below.

```
$ perl -MText::ParseWords -nE '@a=quotewords ",",1,$_;say $a[0],",",$a[1]' <test.txt
"col1","col2"
"col4","col5,subtext"
$
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have `gawk` v4 available, a fine solution exists at [Parse a csv using awk and ignoring commas inside a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205431/parse-a-csv-using-awk-and-ignoring-commas-inside-a-field)

Example:

```
gawk -vFPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]*"' '{print $1 "," $2}' test.txt
```

Comment: The script also needs to work on OS X (i.e. BSD) and so I can't assume gawk is available, unfortunatley.

Comment: Perl to the rescue perhaps, see my other answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another `perl` solution, assuming all fields are quoted

```
$ perl -F'/"\K,(?=")/' -lane 'print "$F[0],$F[1]"' test.txt 
"col1","col2"
"col4","col5,subtext"
```

- `-F'/"\K,(?=")/'` field separator is comma only if it is preceded by `"` and followed by `"`
- `print "$F[0],$F[1]"` print first two fields separated by `,`

Can be done with `grep` as well

```
$ grep -oE '^"[^"]*","[^"]*"' test.txt 
"col1","col2"
"col4","col5,subtext"
```

If N number of fields are needed, use `grep -oE '^("[^"]*",){1}"[^"]*"'` where the number inside `{}` is `N-1`

Answer (score 2):

you can also try this with awk as below;

```
awk -F'","'  '{printf "%s\",\"%s\"\n", $1, $2 }' test.txt
```

Eg;

```
user@host$ awk -F'","'  '{printf "%s\",\"%s\"\n", $1, $2 }' test.txt 
"col1","col2"
"col4","col5,subtext"
```